# gcc4 template bug or more likely id10t error

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-construction, gcc4

The following code compiles just fine under Visual Studio but neither gcc 4.6.2 or 4.7 can handle it.  It seems to be valid but gcc can't seem to resolve the difference between const and non const parameters.  Could this be a compiler bug?

```
struct CReadType{};
struct CWriteType{};

template<typename ReadWriteType, typename T> 
struct AddPkgrConstByType {}; 
template<typename T> 
struct AddPkgrConstByType<CReadType, T> {
   typedef T type;
};    
template<typename T>
struct AddPkgrConstByType<CReadType, const T> {
    typedef T type;
};
template<typename T>
struct AddPkgrConstByType<CWriteType, T> {
    typedef T const type;
};

template<typename Packager, typename T>
struct AddPkgrConst : public AddPkgrConstByType<typename Packager::CReadWriteType, T> {
};

template<typename Packager, typename T>
inline bool Package( Packager* ppkgr, T* pt ) 
{
    return true;
}

template<typename Packager>
inline bool Package( Packager* ppkgr, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager,bool>::type* pb) 
{
    return false;
}

struct ReadPackager {
    typedef CReadType CReadWriteType;
};
struct WritePackager {
    typedef CWriteType CReadWriteType;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ReadPackager rp;
    WritePackager wp;
    bool b = true;
    const bool cb = false;
    Package( &rp, &b );
}
```

Compiler call:

```
g++ -fPIC -O -std=c++0x -Wno-deprecated -D_REENTRANT 
g++-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -c test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:58:22: error: call of overloaded ‘Package(ReadPackager*, bool*)’ is ambiguous
test.cpp:58:22: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:31:6: note: bool Package(Packager*, T*) [with Packager = ReadPackager, T = bool]
test.cpp:38:6: note: bool Package(Packager*, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type*) [with Packager = ReadPackager, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type = bool]
```

Comment: +1 for a complete minimal example program

Comment: @Mr.Anubis : The standard mandates how overload resolution works, so it _shouldn't be_ compiler dependent.

Comment: @ildjarn I got that wrong, Thanks :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis : I'm not sure -- you say "*If you had second argument of type pointer to `typename AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type` then overload could have selected the second one*" but the problem is that in this case `typename AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type` resolves to `bool`, which _is_ what's being passed in, so I'm confused as to what you're getting at.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a compiler error to me. The issues involved here are overload resolution and partial ordering of template functions. Since both template functions can match the argument list `(ReadPackager*, bool)`, partial ordering of template functions should be used to choose the more specialized template function.

Put simply, a template function is at least as specialized as another if the arguments to that function can always be used as arguments to the other.

It's clear that any two pointer arguments match the first Package() function, but for instance Package(ReadPackager*, const int*) can not match the second. This seems to imply that the second Package function is more specialized and ought to resolve any ambiguity.

However, since there is disagreement among the compilers, there may be some subtleties involved that are overlooked by the simplified explanation. I will therefore follow the procedure for determining function template partial ordering from the standard to discern the correct behavior.

First, labeling the functions as P1 and P2 for easy reference.

P1:

```
template<typename Packager, typename T>
bool Package( Packager* ppkgr, T* pt );
```

P2:

```
template<typename Packager>
bool Package( Packager* ppkgr, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager,bool>::type* pb);
```

The standard says that for each template function (T1), we must generic unique type for each of its template parameters, use those types to determine the function call parameter types, and then use those types to deduce the types in the other template (T2). If this succeeds, the first template (T1) is at least as specialized as the second (T2).
First P2->P1

1. Synthesize unique type `U` for template parameter `Packager` of P2.
2. Perform type deduction against `P1`'s parameter list. `Packager` is deduced to be `U` and `T` is deduced to be `AddPkgrConst<Packager,U>::type`.

This succeeds and P1 is judged to be no more specialized than P2.

Now P1->P2:

1. Synthesize unique types `U1` and `U2` for template parameters `Packager` and `T` of P1 to get the parameter list (U1*, U2*).
2. Perform type deduction against `P2`'s parameter list. `Packager` is deduced to be U1.
3. No deduction is performed for the second parameter because, being a dependent type, it is considered a non-deduced context.
4. The second argument is therefore `AddPkgrConst<U1,bool>::type` which evaluates to `bool`. This does not match the second parameter `U2`.

This procedure fails if we proceed to step 4. However, my suspicion is that the compilers that reject this code don't perform step 4 and therefore consider P2 no more specialized than P1 merely because type deduction succeeded. This seems counter intuitive since P1 clearly accepts any input that P2 does and not vice versa. This part of the standard is somewhat convoluted, so it's not clear whether this final comparison is required to be made.

Let's try to address this question by applying §14.8.2.5, paragraph 1, *Deducing template arguments from a type*

> Template arguments can be deduced in several different contexts, but in each case a type that is specified in terms of template parameters (call it P) is compared with an actual type (call it A), and an attempt is made to find template argument values (a type for a type parameter, a value for a non-type parameter, or a template for a template parameter) that will make P, after substitution of the deduced values (call it the deduced A), compatible with A.

In our type deduction, the deduced A is `AddPkgrConst<U1,bool>::type`=`bool`. This is not compatible with the original A, which is the unique type `U2`. This seems to support the position that the partial ordering resolves the ambiguity.

Comment: It's VC++ that's in error, not GCC. His code is resolving to `Package(ReadPackager*, bool*)`, which is very much ambiguous.

Comment: Template ambiguities are supposed to be resolved using template partial ordering. The standard describes the quite complicated procedure involved in determining whether one template is more specialized than another. For instance, "template<typename Packager> Package(Packager*, bool*)" would also take the same arguments as the existing functions, but gcc and other compilers correctly determine that it is more specialized then the first template and do not emit an error.

Comment: Indeed it does, but that's irrelevant. `Package(Packager*, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type*)` is not magically more specialized than `Package(Packager*, T*)` just because it makes use of a metafunction; in this context, both `AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type` and `T` resolve to `bool`. `Package(Packager*, bool*)`, on the other hand, __is__ more specialized. (To be clear, the _reason_ it's irrelevant is because `Packager` in `AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type` is a dependent type.)

Comment: I explained in the original comment why I thought the second Package function was more specialized than the first. There was no magic, and it had nothing to do with dependent types. If you can explain what part of the partial ordering described in the standard makes the second function no more specialized than the first, that would be helpful.

Comment: "*I explained in the original comment why I thought the second Package function was more specialized than the first.*" No you didn't, you just keep mentioning template partial ordering. C++11 §14.5.6.2/3: "*To produce the transformed template, for each type, non-type, or template template parameter (including template parameter packs (14.5.3) thereof) synthesize a unique type, value, or class template respectively and substitute it for each occurrence of that parameter in the function type of the template.*" (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) So after substitutions `Package(Packager*, T*)` becomes `Package(ReadPackager*, bool*)` and `Package(Packager*, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type*)` becomes `Package(ReadPackager*, bool*)`. Then template argument deduction is performed (§14.8.2.4). I admit this part of the standard is terse and lacking clear examples, so I may very well be missing something, but the burden of proof is on _you_. ;-] As far as I can tell, if the second argument of the second overload was `AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>` rather than `AddPkgrConst<Packager, bool>::type` then you would be correct.

Comment: You quoted the standard, but failed to follow the part you quoted. The compiler is supposed to "synthesize a unique type" for each template parameter. The key thing to remember here is that the types used for instantiation have absolutely nothing to do with partial ordering of templates. Example: synthesize types U1, U2 for the first template function to get Package(U1*, U2*). Can those parameters be used to call Package(Packager*, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager,bool>::type*)? After deduction, this is Package(U1*, AddPkgrConst<U1,bool>::type*) or Package(U1*, bool*). U2 is not bool, so no.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not at home yet and a bit rushed; agreed that I didn't follow it correctly, but I quoted the standard partly so _you_ could follow it. Again, the burden of proof is on you to demonstrate why you're right; Comeau, Clang tip-of-trunk, and GCC 4.3-4.6 all reject this simplified version: http://ideone.com/Au8IP Why are they all wrong and you're right?

Comment: Your suggestion that I did not explain why I thought the second function was more specialized than the first and only went on about partial ordering is inaccurate. It is in the second and third paragraphs of the "answer" I originally provided. (I referred to this as my original comment, which may have caused confusion.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not convinced you're correct and that Comeau et al are incorrect until you provide the actual standardese that backs up your statement. Note that I've not downvoted your answer because the potential that you're correct is still there, it will just take a lot of convincing that two _extremely_ conformant compilers are getting this simple thing wrong. :-] (And of course, I'd love to understand the details more clearly, and since you seem to be well-versed in them, so you're in a good position to educate everyone.)

Comment: Using the simplified explanation of the standard from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc16part_ord_fn_tmpl.htm): _A template X is more specialized than a template Y if every argument list that matches the one specified by X also matches the one specified by Y, but not the other way around._, it seems obvious to me that the code _should_ compile. I even tried following the "unique type" substitution from the standard and came to the same conclusion. If the compilers are right, I sure can't figure out why.

Comment: I edited the answer to address with more detail specifically how the standard applies.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and +1 for making a proper answer. :-] I'm going to try to wrap my head around this over the weekend. Oh, and welcome to SO. ;-]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what's wrong with Visual Studio, but what `gcc` says seems right:

You instantiate `AddPkgrConstByType<CReadType, T>` because `Packager::CReadWriteType` resolves to `CReadType`. Therefore, `AddPkgrConst<Packager,bool>::type` will resolve according to the first implementation (which is not a specialisation) to `bool`. This means you have two separate function specialisations with the same parameter list, which C++ doesn't allow you.

Comment: `AddPkgrConst<Packager,bool>::type` does not use any specialization in this context because there is no specialization for `<CReadType, bool>` (only `<CReadType, bool const>`). So, the general (non-specialized) definition is used instead, which also simply does `typedef T type`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks, I actually meant the first implementation, but wrote *specialisation* instead. I'll fix it.

Comment: Actually what gets used is a partial specialisation.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : Ah, you're right; I missed that due to poor formatting (which Mooing Duck fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Since function templates can't be specialized, what you have here is two function template overloads. Both of these overloads are capable of accepting a `bool*` as their second argument so they appear to properly be detected as ambiguous by g++.

However classes *can* be partially specialized so that only one version will be picked, and you can use wrapper magic to attain your desired goal. I'm only pasting the code I added.

```
template <typename Packager, typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    static bool Package()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

template <typename Packager>
struct Wrapper<Packager, typename AddPkgrConst<Packager,bool>::type>
{
    static bool Package()
    {
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename Packager, typename T>
Wrapper<Packager, T> make_wrapper(Packager* /*p*/, T* /*t*/)
{
    return Wrapper<Packager, T>();
}

int main()
{
    ReadPackager rp;
    bool b = true;
    std::cout << make_wrapper(&rp, &b).Package() << std::endl;  // Prints out 0.
}
```

Comment: `AddPkgrConst` is a struct with partial specialization that performs the wrapping in this case. The `const` specialization should be enough to generate a unique type even if it strips the `const` in the `typedef T type` within. This should still be enough to resolve the function overload without ambiguity.